# How to replace vector values with certain proportional weights in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I have a standard graph with 3 node attributes: "a", "b", and "c". I have code that causes the values of "a" and "b" to change constantly and "c" is dependent on these values. To accommodate the changing values I have the following code running in a for loop.

```
V(g)$c[V(g)$a <= V(g)$b] <- sample(c(0, 1), vcount(g), replace = TRUE, prob = c(.9, .1))
```

However it returns the warning:
 number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. and although the code runs, it doesn't take into account the weights for the values. How would I go about fixing this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `sample` statement generates vcount(g) values - one for *every* node in your graph. But you are trying to store these values into `V(g)$c[V(g)$a <= V(g)$b]`.  Presumably sometimes not every node has `V(g)$a <= V(g)$b` so there are fewer spots to store the data.  The simple way to fix this is to generate only the right number of values for the attribute c.  One way to do that would be

```
V(g)$c[V(g)$a <= V(g)$b] <- 
    sample(c(0, 1), sum(V(g)$a <= V(g)$b), replace = TRUE, prob = c(.9, .1))
```

This is just your original statement except that I have replaced `vcount(g)` with `sum(V(g)$a <= V(g)$b)` which counts the number of nodes for which `V(g)$a <= V(g)$b` .